# Creating Lucene Analyzer for German Language

Tags: lucene, analyzer

I use the following chain for analysis of German:
"SimpleTokenizer -> LowerCase -> Stopwords -> Decompounder -> Stopwords - Stemmer"
The Decompounder's type is DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter.
Through I don't know German the result token don't look well.

My questions:
1) Does this chain make scenes in general? In particular, I use Stop twice: before and after Decompounder in order to catch words before and after. Is it correct?
2) Obviously, success of Decompounder depends on quality of dictionary. Please, advice good dictionary for the Decompounder.

Regards,